# Rails - Beginner wants feedback on how they've modeled their app and how to do it better

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I think the way I've modelled my app is a bit fishy and i need to rejig things, im just not sure how. I've already re-jigged and refactored before. It took a long time ( I'm a beginner ) and I'm hesitant to it again in case i head off in the wrong direction again.

Basic Idea, **user** can submit an **answer**, another user can **mark it correct or incorrect**. If incorrect they have to write the correct answer. Users can view their and everybody else's correct and incorrect answers.

So I did it this way

```
class Answer
  has_one: correction
end

class Correction
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

when a user marks an answer as correct, I set checked_at:DateTime and checked_by_id:integer on the Answer object to keep track of who checked the answer and when.

For incorrect answers I create a correction object which holds the correct answer and again checked_by and checked_at details.

I don't like this because I have checked_by and checked_at in both models. It just doesn't sit right.

Possible solutions are:

Create a third model such as VerifiedAnswer and move the checked_by/at attributes to that. It will handle the situtation where an answer is marked correct.

Or are these models thin enough (they dont have any other attributes) that I can just have one model ( Answer ) that has all the attributes to store all this information?

Comment: thanks michael for the spell check - forgot to check my title before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make an answer corrected by another answer. 
That way, you can keep correcting the new answer.

This could be done by specifying:

```
class Answer
  belongs_to :correction, :class_name => "Answer"
end
```

Note that this will mean that any existing answers with corrections will have data set up incorrectly (since the correction_id is currently pointing to a separate table). 
You would need to clear out your database for this to work.

Comment: i was thinking of something like this but what what about in the case where an answer is actually correct?

Comment: in that case, this association would be empty, and answer.correction would be nil. A belongs_to relation is not required

Comment: thanks Faisal - but id need to know who checked it as ok which would mean id need to keep something like checked_by_user_id on the original answer model. So sometimes it would be nil and id have a correction object and other times it wont and I wont have a correction object. I wasn't sure if this was the cleanest way of implementing this.

Comment: I would suggest using:
checked_by_user_id and correction_id.
Then, define a 'needs_checking' method which returns true if they are both false.
Alternatively, a 'correct' method which returns true, false, or nil (depending on whether it is known to be correct, known to be wrong, or not yet corrected).